# Bar Chart on ggplot with Python

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I try to create a chart in Python using ggplot library.

My data is in this format:

```
id total
1  3
1  4
1  7
2  3
2  2
2  5
```

I want to create a bar chart where every id has it's own bar. The y will be the average of total column for the specific id and also add error area with min and max for each bar.

I am new on ggplot. I have worked with scatter plots and line graph but not with bar chart.

I found that bar charts can be created with

`gg = ggplot(mydata, aes(....)) + geom_bar()`

But I cannot figure what to add on aes.

Comment: Ok, in R ggplot there is an [`stat_summary`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/stat_summary.html) for this. I don't see such a function in Python version. I'd recommend to just modify the data and use `ggplot(mydaya, aes(x='factor(x)', y=y)) + geom_bar()`. I'm not sure in the syntax, don't have Python version in a near space.

Answer (score 0):

According to the original R [`ggplot2` docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html) (I've added some bold):

> The heights of the bars commonly represent one of two things: either a
>   count of cases in each group, or the values in a column of the data
>   frame. By default, geom_bar uses stat="bin". This makes the height of
>   each bar equal to the number of cases in each group, and it is
>   incompatible with mapping values to the y aesthetic. **If you want the
>   heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use
>   stat="identity" and map a value to the y aesthetic.**

This also works in the amazing Python port:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x='id', y='total')) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Which looks like:
[image: Simple ggplot bar chart]

The x ticks are obviously a bit weird in this case, but I'll leave that for another question!